# Can we build tensorflow lite on distro's other than Raspberry Pi such as Ubuntu/CentOS?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

The official documentation [Tensorflow Lite on Raspberry Pi](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/rpi) says it can be build on Raspberry Pi, but are there any instructions/information on how to build it on other Linux distributions such as Ubuntu/CentOS/RedHat. Is it possible to build at all?

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi default distribution is Rasbian, which is based on Debian. Ubuntu is also based on Debian. Therefore you can probably use most of the RPi instructions also on Debian/Ubuntu.

For other Linux distro families like CentOS/RHEL/Fedora you will need a different way to install the dependencies, but in general the process should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The official guide of building tflite on Raspbian may not be complete, but actually works.
As for other Linux distributions, your link did show how to compile on Ubuntu 16.04; you can build on PC and then copy the binary&symbolic link the library to run .tflite models on RPi.